# How does Xorg manage multiple monitors if there's only one framebuffer?

Tags: linux, framebuffer, xorg

X manages to display different things on each display even though if you write a frame to /dev/fb0 it will be identical on all displays connected to that GPU. What does X do differently than the framebuffer? Does it bypass the frame buffer?

Comment: Why would xorg bother using an abstraction like framebuffer at all? Xorg is very big, and there are drivers that use GPU directly, not via any framebuffers.

Comment: I understand why, I was wondering how. Recently I was working on a project involving multiple monitors and was annoyed that I couldn't use frame-buffer because it only exposed one fb per gpu not per monitor.